# "No message" error laravel - trying to update user account information

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I'm receiving the error **"MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message"** on submit of my user's form, which is meant to update the user's table. I have two post forms on the same page and two post routes, would that have something to do with it?

I will include all the routes and another form that might be conflicting with it.

web.php

```
Route::get('profile','userController@profile');
Route::post('profile', 'userController@update_avatar');
Route::post('profile-update', 'userController@update_account'); //this ones not working
```

userController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\User;

use Auth;

use Image;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function profile()
    {
        return view('profile', array('user' => Auth::user()) );
    }

    public function update_avatar(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
            $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($avatar)->resize(300,300)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename) );

            $user = Auth::user();
            $user->avatar = $filename;
            $user->save();

        }
        return view('profile', array('user' => Auth::user()) );
    }

    public function update_account(Request $request, $id) //the function with the error
    {

         User::update([ 
                'id' => Auth::user()->id,
                'name' => $request->name,
                'email' => $request->email
            ]);
            return redirect('/profile');

    }
}
```

profile.blade.php

```
 <img src="/uploads/avatars/{{ $user->avatar }}" style="width:150px;height:150px;float:left;border-radius:50%;margin-right:25px">    
                <h2>{{ $user->name }}'s Profile</h2>

                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/profile" method="post">
                    <label>Update Profile Image</label>
                    <input type="file" name="avatar">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                    <input type="submit" class=" btn btn-sm btn-light" style="color:#2b2b2b;" value="Update Image">
                </form>

                <form method="post" action="/profile-update"> <!-- The form with the error -->
                    {{ method_field('put') }}
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->name }}">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="{{ $user->email }}">
                    <input type="submit" id="update-account" class="btn btn-success" value="Update">

                </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this method:

```
public function update_account(Request $request, $id) 
{
    $user = User::find($id)
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->update();

    return redirect('/profile');
}
```

Comment: The page doesn't load now, I just get this error **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$user' (T_VARIABLE)**

Comment: my bad
 replace the  $user = User::find($id) with this $user = User::find($Auth::user()->id)

Comment: if your editing your own account then you can use $user = User::find($Auth::user()->id) if not then, you need to put the user id of user you want to update in your parameter like Route::post('profile-update/{id}', 'userController@update_account') then catch the id in public function update_account(Request $request, $id) then you can use now $user = User::find($id) and do what you want and make sure call  $user->update(); so it will update items inside in your database

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work with `$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);`

Comment: take note: Auth::user()->id it will work only if you edit only your own user.
if you wish to edit other users then you use your parameter $id and supply it first from your source either javascript or php

Comment: Awww I see, I'll know that for the future thanks! This case is just for a user editing their own account details, so it works for now. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any route which can handle the PUT request for "profile-update". In your form you have defined the following function.

```
{{ method_field('put') }}
```

This helper function generate an hidden input field which will be used by Laravel to process the current request only as PUT.

To make this work, you either have to make your make your request POST by removing the above helper function or change your route method to PUT.

```
Route::put('profile-update', 'userController@update_account');
```

Comment: Used the route method put and now getting this error **"Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\UserController::update_account(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected"** is it cause I haven't included $id in the function? @alley

Comment: You have defined a parameter in the controller method you have to add it in the route definition too. Something like Route::put('profile-update/{id}', 'userController@update_account'); then you also have to change the form action and pass it the correct url.

Comment: Done.. now the error is **Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::update() should not be called statically** thank you for all your help!

Comment: You first need to find the user using the id. Something like $user = User::find($id); and then save the user information or use the update method like this.                                                                         User::where('id', $id)->update([ 
                'name' => $request->name,
                'email' => $request->email
            ]);.                                                                                                    I also recommend reading the Laravel documentation, it's very good.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I got it to work :) @alley

Answer (score 0):

For those that might need the same answer, to fix this I had to play about with it for quite some time and used bits from the suggested answers to solve the issue completely.

1. I changed the route method to put in web.php.
2. Replaced my update_account function with @TonzFale answer but replaced `$user = User::find($id)`with `$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);`.